# Protected archive (7z, RAR, Zip) open at a specific time

Tags: security, timestamps, archive

Are there any compression tools that are unopenable or password-protected until a specific time, at when the security is then lifted?

Literally an enforced: "Do not open until --/--/----"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a computer science question.

Can this be done at all? It it possible?

The naive answer: Alice gives bob locked file and key, but first makes bob promises that he will not unlock it until it is time.

Alice gives locked file to Bob, and key to Clare. Alice instructs Clare to give key to Bob at pre-defined time.

For the case of writing special software to do the decoding. Then this software is Clare. Bob can manipulate Clare: including reverse engineering, or simply feeding a false time to Clare.

Alice gives locked file to Bob, and key to Clive. Alice instructs Clive to publish key) at pre-defined time. (This avoids Clive having to know about Bob, and maybe Bob having to know about Clive. This reduces risk of collaboration, before set date.)

What changes in the future to make it possible for Bob to unlock Alices file: What can Bob know in the future (so that he can unlock the file), but is impossible for Bob to know now(so he can not unlock it yet). But it is possible for Alice to know now (so that Alice can lock the file now)? **If** you can answer this, then I think it can be done.

A possible answer: Alice gives Bob the locked file. At a time in the future Alice sends/publishes/transmits the key.

Comment: I had no idea this was such a problem, though you have rationalized it perfectly. Thanks, I believe I will just give Bob the password to the archive at a given time

Answer (score 1):

First, note that compression has nothing to do with encryption. There are tools that do both, but the two parts of functionality are independent.

Cryptography is about information processing. It can be described as mathematical transformations. Mathematics doesn't depend on the date. If I can decrypt something today, I could already decrypt it yesterday, assuming I have received no new information since yesterday. If you want to make something decryptable after a certain date but not before, you have to provide extra information at that date.

There is one way to make a sort of time release for encrypted data: require a vast amount of brute force effort to find the key, and tune that effort to the time you want your encrypted data to resist decryption. This doesn't permit a release at a precise date: the uncertainty is measured in years. It has a chance of working because improvements in computing power are exponential, so you don't get much of an advantage by starting to break the key now rather than starting in 10 years with the computers of that time. It is sensitive to the amount of computation that your adversary may want to expend compared to the amount of computation that legitimate users want to expend. At best it has an imprecision of a few years on the release date. This is only appropriate for extremely specific use cases.

If you want an encrypted file to become decryptable at a certain date, the only possible solution is to use non-cryptographic means. Keep the key for yourself until the release date. If you can't or don't want to keep in control of the key, get someone to do it for you (a type of key escrow, where you, the recipient of the encrypted file and the escrow service enter an agreement to release the key at a certain date).

Comment: very interesting, I will do just that